# Angular: @input doesn't seems to be working

Tags: angular

I have just started learning the Angular and begin by following [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fdf5aTYRW0E&t=). But, it looks like that @Input is not working here. Here is the model class to store data:

**Todo.ts:**

```
export class Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  complete: boolean;
  optional?: string;
}
```

Todos component along with data:
**todos.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Todo} from '../../models/Todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todos',
  templateUrl: './todos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todos.component.css']
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[];

  constructor() { }

  strTest = 'A test string';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.todos = [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'One',
          complete: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'two',
          complete: true,
          optional: 'an optional item'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'three',
          complete: false
        }

    ];

  }

}
```

**todos.component.html**

```
<p>todos from local class</p>
<!-- Working -->
<ul *ngFor='let td of todos'>
  <li>{{td.title}}</li>
</ul>


<p> From todo-item class</p>
<!-- Not Working -->
 <app-todo-item *ngFor="let todo of todos"  [todos]="todo" > </app-todo-item>
```

*Following is where **selector app-todo-item** is defined and @Input from Todo is performed:*

**todo-item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from 'src/app/models/Todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-item',
  templateUrl: './todo-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-item.component.css']
})
export class TodoItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() todos: Todo;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.todos.title);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And **todos-item.component.html**, which is supposed to display the values

```
 <div>
  <p> {{ todos.title }}  </p>

</div>
```

I'm not able to find the missing piece here. 
Please help..
Thanks

Comment: `@Input` values aren't loaded yet in the constructor, try checking it in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` instead.

Comment: check this demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdzavy

Comment: @malbarmavi. Thanks this is a very useful demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), `ngOnChanges` is used to “Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values. Called before `ngOnInit()` and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.” , so a good place to start check the data will be ngOnInit life cycle hook

```js
export class TodoItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() todos: Todo;

 constructor() {
  /*
  Don't access, initialize, modify at constructor. 
  Misko Hevery, Angular team lead, explains why you should avoid complex constructor logic.
  Link --> http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/
  */

  //console.log(this.todos.title);                                     
 }    

 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.todos.title);
 }

}
```

read this [exploring angular lifecycle hooks onchanges](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/exploring-angular-lifecycle-hooks-onchanges)

Answer (score 3):

Use the **optional chaining operator** in your template (`todos-item.component.html`). If `todos` is null/undefined at the beginning you can break the template rendering (cannot access `title` from undefined) and cause an unrecoverable javascript error that prevents anything else from working in this component. Add this:

```html
<div>
  <!-- NOTICE THE "?" after todos -->
  <p> {{ todos?.title }}  </p>
</div>
```